# [発見]{はっ・けん} and [発明]{はつ・めい} difference

Tags: word-choice, kanji

I'm trying to memorize the kanji 発 and a few of its most important usages in vocab.

Jisho says はっけん means discovery and はつめい means invention. Aren't these synonyms of each other? They are both used in, for example, a scientific context or for new technologies. What are the differences?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can safely follow the difference of discovery/invention for 発見/発明, I suppose.

- 彼は遺跡を{発見した/*発明した} : He discovered/*invented  the remains.
- 彼はラジオを{*発見した/発明した}： He *discovered/invented radio.

発明した is used usually for things made by the subject, just like *invent*.
Let me know if I'm wrong in the assumption.

Comment: If I am making the correct conclusion with your answer "はっけん" means more like "to find" "found"? "Stumbled upon"?

Comment: Yes, 見つける/発見する are mostly interchangeable. One thing worth noting about difference between 発明する and _invent_ is that 発明する cannot be used in the sense of telling a lie. E.g. _He invented a story_ / *彼は話を発明した (でっちあげた is the correct verb here).